# angularJS hit ASP.MVC controller to export excel

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC controller to export excel file :

```
public ActionResult exportExcelBankData(BankDataViewModel viewModel) {

        List<BankDataViewModel> bankDatas = (List<BankDataViewModel>)Session["bankDatas"];
        bankDatas = bankDatas.OrderBy(x => x.completeLoading).ToList();

        using (var package = new ExcelPackage()) {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            string fileName = "bankData.xlsx";
            string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

            //fill rows and columns

            package.SaveAs(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;
            return File(stream, contentType, fileName);
        }
    }
```

and here my angularjs function to hit the controller

```
 labAnalysisService.exportExcel = function (val, obj) {
    return $http.get( val, //url to controller
      { params: obj, //parameter
        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' } 
      });
}
```

and I'am still unable to export the excel.

any suggestion?

Comment: is end point hitting ? if yes what do you get in response ?

Answer (score 0):

A File returned with ajax call will not be downloaded, you have to make following changes.
Make request of the excel download by opening a new window of browser through java script like this

```
         window.open(
        "Controller/Action?args=" + encodeURIComponent(val),
        "_blank");
```